# DataGridView Default Row/Cell select issue

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, selectionchanged

DataGridView set to Full Row Select.
Need a way to clear the default selected row thats done by the default nature of DataGridView

I am also using SelectionChanged event
That dgv has 4 columns

If i leave the default row selection, SelectionChanged fires 4 times when its loaded which I don't want it to fire at all.

I have tried using the RowsPostPaint event which clears the selection and doesn't fire the SelectionChanged event but i'm unable to select any rows after.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: The current work around I have is below but is there a better way?
I store int p = 0
Then I run if p != 3; p++; ClearSelection
once the value reaches 3 it continues the SelectionChanged method

Answer (score 0):

To de-select the initial row selection, you can enumerate the `SelectedRows` and set the `Selected` property to `false`.  To prevent the `SelectionChanged` event from firing when the initial row is selected, add the event manually, after you de-select it.

For example, in the form's `Load` event:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    row.Selected = false;

dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += dataGridView1_SelectionChanged;
```

Comment: Been trying to implement the above in some way but having issues.
Here is the run down of the app:

ListView, TabControl with multiple tabs.
Within a few tabs contain the DataGridViews.

Selecting an item from the ListView populates all the data in the tabs/DataGridView's
When selecting an item from the ListView it resets the tab index back to 0 which that tab doesn't contain a dgv.

When that data is populated I need to clear the default selected row which is always the first populated since i'm using SelectedChanged

Comment: A new item gets selected in the ListView and clears out the dgv for the new data
again triggering SelectedChanged event and the need to clear it before it hits the event again.

Hope I'm explaining this as well as I can

Answer (score 0):

use this

in form loading:

```
     datagridview.DataBindingComplete += new DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(datagridview_DataBindingComplete);
```

and for the listener:

```
    private void datagridview_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        datagridview.ClearSelection();
    }
```

bute note that anytime you change datasource your default selection hides.

Comment: Also, DataBindingComplete doesn't just run when databinding is complete, but whenever a *cell* has bound. So if you want to do anything heavier than clearing the selection, the event is close to useless if not worse than useless.

Answer (score 0):

After populating datagrid,try this one.

> datagrid.ClearSelection();